# Computer turns on at 3 AM for the first time in 2 years

Tags: windows-7, boot, hibernate, wake-on-lan

I was doing some c# coding on my laptop when I suddently hear my workstation turn on at exactly 3AM. I always turn my computer into hibernate, but they never ever booted themselves before. I got the computer for 2 years. It's an HP xw4600 with an SSD installed as primary hard drive using windows 7. I didn't change any windows settings or bios settings lately, suddently it started. I searched in the cmd what booted my computer, the source was unknown. There was no maintance needed and Wake-on-lan is disabled.

I'm not too sure what caused it, it just booted, i waited for 5 minutes.. Nothing happened. So i put it in hibernate again. What could have caused it and how do I prevent this happening again.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that you did not change anything - go to your BIOS settings and check if there is "Auto power on" schedule set or not. Also, check what is the setting for "Power" for case of power loss (Previous state, always OFF, always ON).

Comment: "Didn't change any Windows settings": On my Vista machine, that meant Windows would wake from hibernation at 3AM every Sunday to download and install updates. Did it for years, before I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

On my personal PC, I use Windows Task Scheduler to automatically perform scheduled tasks, including hibernating/sleeping and waking the computer at specific times. You might want to check Task Scheduler to make sure nothing is causing an interference. These can be set to only operate every now and then, so this could be what you just witnessed.